# Alternative to display:none using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement of keeping a div hidden and make it visible when user performs an action.

But, due to dependencies on an external script, I cannot use `style="display:none"` for my div.

Therefore, to meet the requirement, I am thinking of using `style="visibility:hidden,height:0"` for my div and when user performs an action, make it visible using jquery by changing the style to `"visibility:visible,height:auto"` which I have tested and working fine.

Is there any issue with the approach I have used when using in computers and mobiles? Whether any browser prevent content on a div which has height 0?

I have seen some posts in this forum suggesting to use of "position:absolute" along with height changes to meet this objective. So, is it needed to change the div to absolute or my approach of changing the visibility and height is fine?

Comment: have you tried to use "display: none !important" ?

Comment: Why in particular can you not use ```display: none```? Are you able to toggle a CSS class instead of using inline styles?

Comment: I cannot use display: none because I use mathjax library to load mathematics. this library needs the width and height of the container to load properly and when it comes to divs with display:none, it attach the content to body, process it and load it back to the original div. see https://www.peterkrautzberger.org/0165/

Comment: If, for some weird reason, you can't use `display:none`, you could move the element outside of the visible range (like far negative top and absolute position)

Comment: You have answer over [here](https://www.peterkrautzberger.org/0165/#the-moral)

Comment: @Vilas Kumar, I had gone through this. Do you think height:0 and restoring the height work fine everywhere? I have tested this and to me it appears that it is working everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could move your element outside the visible range by adding a CSS class:

```
.custom-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5000px; //use !important if needed
}
```

Comment: yes, it is fine. but, i was trying to understand whether any issue is there with my approach suggested

Answer (score 0):

You solution is suitable, else you can still try

```
1) opacity: 0;

2) position: absolute;
   left: -9000px;

3) transform: scale(0)
```